# Is there in Qt built-in data strucutre that ignore duplicate insertion of item?

Tags: c++, list, qt, data-structures

I would use a [QSet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qset.html) but I need to preserve the order that the items were inserted as I need to loop over that list later.

```
 QSet<QString> notes;
    notes << "a" << "b" << "c" << "a";
    foreach(const QString &note, notes)
        qDebug() << note;
```

will output:

```
a
c
b
```

instead of:

```
a
b
c
```

I know I can do:

```
if(!list.contains(item))
            list << item;
```

Or implement any better appraoch my own. I just want to know if there's a native data structure that usually is faster and well-tested, etc...

Comment: If it isn't [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/containers.html), and there isn't a newer documentation, no. You don't have it in STL, either. Make a generic adapter that does what you want.

Comment: Depending on your needs (e.g., how important is memory usage versus insertion speed) you could create a class that makes uses of `std::vector<std::set<std::string>::iterator>` and `std::set<std::string>`. This allows you quickly check if it's already contained and preserve the order of insertion, obviously with some storage overhead. (or equivalent Qt classes)

Comment: If your collections are going to be sufficiently small, you may as well use the list approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the order of insertion *and* avoid duplicates, then there's nothing ready-to-go in Qt.

A simple helper function would do the job:

```
template <typename T>
bool appendUnique(QList<T> & data, QSet<T> & index, const T & value) {
  if (index.contains(value))
    return false;
  data.append(value);
  index.insert(value);
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Basically what I ended up writing. Thanks